# android studio common sdk folder for all users

Tags: android-studio

I am using Android Studio 2.2.3 from two user accounts on Windows 10. Whenever I update plug-ins, it doesn't seem to have updated for all users. How to move make studio point to a common folder that can contain the sdk and apply all updates there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Studio SDK is usually installed under **C:\Users\%USER%\AppData\Local\Android\sdk** folder. If you want to access it from different user, you should consider installing it on a different drive or configure & move your current SDK to a different drive. That should do the work.
**Haven't tried yet but this should surely work.**

Comment: Yes! if you install sdk on a different drive it can be used by all users. It works!!